# How to propagate request values to context using ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm migrating a project from Django to Express and to make it simple I'm passing my `req.user0` & `req.isAuth` values into the view as a variable through the context like so:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        isAuth: req.isAuth, // check if user is auth.
        user: req.user      // get user's profile or False.
    })
});
```

This works however I have many routes and I want to avoid repeating them. Is there a more efficient way to include those values as variables into my view (`.pug` file) without having to precise them in each route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom middlewars, have a look at
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: I know about middlewares, but how do I pass it to context? Since `req.user` is already from a custom middleware, how can I retrieve it from the pug file?

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood, if you want to check user state you can use sessions, https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Comment: Sessions won't cut it either since it has to be a one time get request to access those variables, it shouldn't be stored. But maybe in express it's unusual to do so, I probably have to use an endpoint and manage the templating with react instead?